# How to change the way to access property in an object?

Tags: javascript, object

The task is to change the way to access a property on an object and change the dot operator to a function that will have two arguments: an object and a property.

```
  var exObject = {
      arr: [],
      obj: {},
      str: 'string',
      num: 22,
      boolean: false,
      undeFined: undefined,
      nullValue: null
    }
```

for example: `typeof change(exObject, "str")` should result in  `string`;

```
function change(obj,property){
var prop="";
    for (var key in obj){
        if ([key]==property){
            prop=obj[key].constructor;
            }
        }
return prop;
}
```

My code is clearly wrong - would be happy about any suggestions!

Comment: what is the benefit of such an approach in compared to direct object property access? How do you think?

Comment: I really can't see the benefit, maybe you can enlighten me :)

Comment: If this retrieves a property value, why is it called `change`? Why are you comparing an array containing `key` with `property`? Why are you returning the constructor of the value instead of the value itself? Why are you continuing to loop after finding the property? What is the difference between your function and one that just returns `obj[property]`?

Comment: Your question is unclear in several places. Let's address the first: the statement that you want to change the dot operator to take an object and a property. The dot operator is operating on an object to start with, so your result would be the rather nonsensical `exObject.(exObject, 'str')` is that actually what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand maybe this will work for you

```
function chang(obj, property){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(property)){
        return obj[property];
    }
    return null;
}
```

PS: the property needs to be a string, such as 'arr'